# accessing a nameless function inside an object type

Tags: typescript

So I recently came across this type e.g.

```
type a = {
    (name : string) : string;
    (name : string, id : number) : string;
}
```

how would I create a type that references specifically one of the functions?

e.g.

```
type b = a["something"] // this should equal (name : string) : string
```

Comment: This cannot be done; see the linked q/a for more info, plus [ms/TS#29732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29732) for the feature request.  Note: you're calling this a "nameless function" but the conventional terminology is just "call signature", and in particular you are trying to access a single call signature from an *overloaded* function type.